# Regex: Repeat captured group

Tags: regex

For the following generated HTML

```
<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
Static text
<a href="http://Bing.com">bing.com</a>
<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
Static text
<a href="http://Bing.com">bing.com</a>
<a href="http://Bing.com">bing.com</a>
```

I need to match(pseudo):

```
(Single URL) \nStatic text\n (Multiple URLs)
```

Like:

```
MATCH 1
1. 'http://google.com'
2. 'http://Bing.com'

MATCH 2
1. 'http://google.com'
2. 'http://Bing.com'
3. 'http://Bing.com'
```

For this example, **how do I repeat a captured group?**

My attempt:

```
(http:\/\/[a-zA-Z.-_]{1,}){1}[">.a-zA-Z<>\/]{1,}\nStatic text\n[">.a-zA-Z<>\/ =]{1,}(http:\/\/[a-zA-Z.-_]{1,}){1,}
```

(See also https://regex101.com/r/cJ2wJ6/5), which does not seem to do the trick. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What you quote of your 'tried' regex doesn't match the anchor tag markup properly.  You've also not allowed for `https` URLs, but that's trivia.  You need to look hard at the material in the square brackets before the second `http:` section, and you need something along those lines after it too (you've not allowed for the newlines in the data you show either, for instance).

Comment: don't use regex to parse html.

Comment: `(?:CAPTURING_GROUP)*`